# how to make node data available in the page.tpl.php

Tags: theming, 7

I want to be able to print the contents of my node tpl up into the outer page region, accessible via the page.tpl.php (or an override). How exactly can I do this?

I originally thought about doing a variable_set in the node.tpl and then getting it in the page.tpl. However, if this would work, I would need to be able to create a template. I tried page--node--gallery-photo.tpl.php, but it doesn't seem to be the correct override.

What this the best way to do what I need to do here?

Comment: `page.tpl.php` already has the `$node` object? Am I missing something in your question?

Comment: I think I somehow missed that (still a little new with templates). I assume that is what I want. But the second question is now: is there a theme template suggestion which would specify pages with node type X, or would I just need do an if statement using the node type from $node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Drupal 7 you can edit your theme's `template.php` and add (or edit) the function

```
function <YOUR_THEME_NAME>_preprocess_page(&$vars) { 
  if (isset($vars['node']->type)) { 
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $vars['node']->type; 
  } 
}
```

The same task in Drupal 6 is accomplished by adding/editing in template.php

```
function <YOUR_THEME_NAME>_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['node']->type)) {
    $variables['template_files'][] = "page-" . $variables['node']->type;
  }
}
```

Then you can add `page--<YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME>.tpl.php` (or `page-<YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME>.tpl.php` in Drupal 6)  to your theme. Remember to clear the theme cache.